# How to make a Discord Bot (Javascript) react to reactions

Tags: javascript, discord

I've been trying to make a text-based game using a Javascript Discord Bot, and I can't figure out how to make the bot send a message upon the user sending a reaction (i.e. player reacting to bot message with a certain emoji).

```
client.on("message", message => { 
  if (message.content === "!start") {
    message.channel.send("Hello")
  }

  if (message.content === "Hello") {
    message.react("")
  }

  if (message.react === "") {
    message.channel.send("You walk into the labyrinth")
  }
)}
```

Is it possible for someone to help correct whatever's wrong?

Comment: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#listening-for-reactions-on-old-messages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a dedicated event for it but you can catch the reaction event by using `raw`:

```js
const events = {
    MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD: "messageReactionAdd",
    MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE: "messageReactionRemove"
};

client.on("raw", async (event, client) => {
    if (!events.hasOwnProperty(event.t)) return;

    const { d: data } = event;

    const message = await client.channels.cache.get(data.channel_id).messages.fetch(data.message_id);

    if (event.d.emoji.name !== ""){
        message.channel.send("You walk into the labyrinth");
    }

    // ...

    if (event.t === "MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD"){
        // Reaction was added
    }
    else if (event.t === "MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE"){
        // Reaction was removed
    }
});
```

**Edit:** Seems like [there is a dedicated event](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#listening-for-reactions-on-old-messages).